# isUserUnlocked() vs isUserRunningAndUnlocked()

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

In `android.os.UserManager`, what is the difference between these methods?

```
public boolean isUserUnlocked ({ε|UserHandle})
public boolean isUserRunningAndUnlocked ({ε|UserHandle})
```

As far as I can read, the documentation text is the same:

> Return whether the {calling|given} user is running in an "unlocked"
>   state. A user is unlocked only after they've entered their credentials
>   (such as a lock pattern or PIN), and credential-encrypted private app
>   data storage is available.

Comment: Could you provide a link to where you got the quote from?

Comment: It is an the N-preview reference documentation package: http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#docs-dl

Comment: My guess would be isUserUnlocked can be used in background apps to see if the user is unlocked, isUserRunningAndUnlocked could be used to check if the user is also running the app. Im not sure though

Comment: `isUserRunningAndUnlocked` seems to be deprecated and removed now.

Apart from this, both APIs have the same implementation: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.2_r6/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java#1006